# Solving $(p-n)\bmod\:\left(\sqrt{n}\right)\:=\:0$ for $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

I have the equation $$(p-n)\bmod\:\left(\sqrt{n}\right)\:=\:0$$ where $p$ is known.

n is a perfect square.  Is there a fast algorithm or method to find solutions to this equation?

Comment: This is hard to read.

Comment: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it I think

Comment: Is $n$ assumed to be a perfect square?  What is $n\pmod {\sqrt n}$ if not $0$?

Comment: n is assumed to be a perfect square, and I am pretty sure this only has a finite amount of solutions iff p is semi-prime.  also its not n mod root(n) its (p-n)mod(root(n)), like the whole quantity p-n

Comment: @Yoursole: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Please [edit the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4481139/edit) to add clarifications or other context. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.

Comment: Um.... As $n = \sqrt{n} \times \sqrt{n}$ we have $n\equiv 0 \pmod {\sqrt n}$ and we are have only the solution $p-n \equiv p\equiv 0 \pmod {\sqrt n}$.  ... BTW.... this wouldn't look so perplexing and had let $n = m^2$ so we'd have $p - m^2 \pmod m$.  Does that look more sensible.

Comment: @fleablood I may be misunderstanding but I think you are saying that this is p - (n mod root(n)), but it is (p-n) all mod (root(n))

Comment: You are misunderstanding me (and lulu).   $n \equiv 0 \pmod {\sqrt n}$.  (It's easier to see if we replace $\sqrt = m$ and $m^2 \equiv 0 \pmod n$).  Therefore $p-n \equiv p-0 \pmod {\sqrt \n}$.  So if $p - n\equiv 0\pmod{\sqrt n}$ then $p \equiv 0 \pmod {\sqrt n}$. ... or alternatively we can solve $p-n\equiv 0 \pmod n\implies p \equiv n \equiv 0 \pmod {\sqrt n}$.

Comment: @fleablood sorry to misunderstand, I know basically nothing of number theory or what stuff means.  if p is identical to 0 mod root(n), then doesn't p need to equal 0 because 0 mod anything is 0 I thought?  Sorry for the likely silly questions xD

Comment: $p$ can be any multiple of $\sqrt n$.  We don't solve for individual integers but sets of all integers that differ by a multiple of the modulus.  For example, if $x \equiv 7 \pmod {10}$ the $x$ can be $7$ or $17$ or $27$ or $-3$ or $327483927583927$.  We don't actually care which one.  We only care that $x = 7 + 10k$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: @fleablood so say we set p = 989, how would we use this to solve for n?  Like in this case I happen to know that n = 529, 1849, or 978121; But how does this solution get to these answers?

Comment: You didn't say you were trying so solve of $n$.  I assumed you knew $n$ and were trying to solve for $p$.  Okay.  If $p = 989$ and we now that $989 - m^2\equiv 0 \pmod m$ and we want to solve of $m$ then we know that $989-m^2 \equiv 989 \pmod m$ so $989\equiv 0 \pmod m$.  That means $m|989$. As $989 = 23\times 43$ we have that $m$ must equal either $1, 23, 43$ or $989$.  So $n = 1, 529, 1849$ or $978121$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get rid of the square root sign, let's set $n = m^2$ where $m$ is a natural number. Then let's first review the definition of congruence modulo $m$:

$a \equiv b \mod m$ means that $m | a - b$, i.e. $m$ divides the difference between $a$ and $b$, or equivalently there exists an integer $k$ such that $a - b = km$.

Then, if we have $p \equiv m^2 \mod m$, this means that $m^2 - p = km$ for some integer $k$, but we can rearrange that to give $p = m^2 - km = m(m - k)$.

If $p$ is a known value, then this just boils down to saying that $m$ must be some factor of $p$, and hence $n$ is going to be the square of a factor of $p$.